# In Azure DevOps Pipilines , unable to find docker file to build

Tags: azure-devops

here are the Code

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
pr: none

variables:
- name: triggerBranch
  value: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

stages:

- stage: clone
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job

    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
       containerRegistry: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
       repository: 'loginpage'
       command: 'buildAndPush'
       Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
       buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
       tags: $(Build.BuildId)
```

Instead of this I also used "'$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/login-page/Dockerfile'" but same error
as

##[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/Dockerfile  was found.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/Dockerfile  was found.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/Dockerfile  was found.

I think checkout is not taking place properly

Please help me out

That should be run  if it find dockerfile

Comment: Is your repository being checked out prior to this step running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and ensure the **`Dockerfile`** and the pipeline YAML file (such as **`azure-pipelines.yml`**) are existing together in the same repository, the same branch and the same source version.

---

In addition, before the **Docker@2** task, you also can add a **`Bash@3`** task to run the "**`ls -R`**" command to list all the files under the directory **`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`**.

If the **`Dockerfile`** is not existing, maybe the **checkout** task has issue to check out all the source files from the source version that triggered the run. As a workaround, you can try to disable the **checkout** task and use a **`Bash@3`** task to run the '**`git clone`**' command to check out the source files.

```yaml
    steps:
    # Disable the checkout task.
    - checkout: none

    # Use 'git clone' command to check out the source files.
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Check out soucre files'
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: git clone --branch $(Build.SourceBranchName) --depth 1 https://buildagent:$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_git/{Repository}
```

Comment: @paritoshmishra, Is there any update from you?